# How to get npm module working locally on Laravel/Vue Project?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, node-modules

I know the question is broad but at this point I'm not necessarily sure how to specify it. I am currently working on a Laravel/Vue project, and I want to create an extracted module that will eventually be an NPM package. The reason I want to extract it is because I will use this chunk of code as a `mixin` within various Vue components.

I want to do this all locally so that I don't have to continuously mess with NPM, so I set up the link between my `project` and my `module` via the `npm link` command. I can confirm in my Project that there is a symbolic link directory in the `node_modules` directory, pointing to my Module.

In my Project, I have the code from the mixin executing a function inside another method of my Vue component, like so:

```
this.updateState(response.state);
```

I am importing and defining the mixin in that file like so:

```
import UpdatesState from 'module';

export default {
    mixins: [UpdatesState],
```

This `updateState` method is defined in my Module. Inside my Module, here is what my `module/src/mixins/UpdateState` file looks like:

```
export default {
methods: {
    updateState(state) {
        this.$store.commit('state', state);
    }
},
}
```

Also in the Module, I have an `index.js` file that looks like this:

```
import UpdatesState from './mixins/UpdatesState'

export default {
    UpdatesState
}
```

My Module's `package.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "module",
    "description": "Supporting modules",
    "main": "src/index.js",
    "author": "Hoolakoola",
    "license": "MIT"
}
```

When I was running this code from within the actual source of the Project and just referencing it by its absolute path, it was working fine. But now that I am trying to extract it, it is not working properly. I am not getting any errors when compiling the Project, and there are no errors in the console. Any idea what is going wrong here and how I can fix it? Thank you.

Comment: The project should not compile successfully unless it is able to find the import, so it is likely finding your code okay (unless there is a naming conflict for `import UpdatesState from 'module';` but that would likely error too). The code is probably being built into a vendors.js file or something similar, depending on whether you're using vue-cli or a customized setup. Does that code look correct? Also, please specify what "not working properly" means. Maybe it's just an integration bug?

Comment: @AlexMA Apologies I should have been more clear. By "not working" I mean the Module's function isn't running at all, and the script dies at the point where the function is called in my Project. I'm trying a couple different things now. I am new to this whole process, and am not really sure the best way to go about it. My thought was that I would just export this function as a Module, utilize it in my project, and compile it in my Project to my `app.js`. This is what I'm currently doing, but maybe I need to compile from the Module?